# How do I drift in Vertigo Racing?

Tags: vertigo-racing

In the mobile game Vertigo Racing I've noticed that challenges will periodically pop up when trying to complete cups such as "Drift for X seconds."  I'm confused on how to properly drift.  Breaking normally does not trigger a drift.  I've noticed that breaking into corners does allow my car to drift, but it usually does not last more than a a tenth of a second or so.  While this works, if the challenge is "Drift for 60 seconds" this will take quite a few races in order to complete.

Is there a trick to execute longer drifts around corners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized one of the things I was doing wrong was tapping the brake while still holding the accelerator.  Just tapping or holding the brake without holding the gas while my car was moving around corners allowed me to execute longer drifts, especially on a level like Nordpeaks.